# How to get the last 7 Days Dates in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, datetime, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm having a Report where I need to display the dates of `last 7 days`.

As shown below

[image]

**Sun, Mon etc...** are hard coded and the `Dates` are written in `Expression`

***For example,***

If today is `Wednesday` I need to show the Dates till last `Tuesday`.

If it is `Thursday` I need to show the Dates till last `Wednesday`.

How to retrieve the dates information and display below the corresponding days.

Comment: It'll be something like: DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)

Comment: Pavan, you can achieve this by SQL query (Dataset) and by using `DateTime.Now.AddDays()` - set one parameter to today's date and then set seven different expression (by doing +1) to header as well as to column.

Answer (score 1):

To get last seven days date you can do something like below in each expression,

***To get Days in Header***

```
=WeekdayName(weekday(Parameters!TodaysDate.Value)) --Tuesday
=WeekdayName(weekday(DateAdd("d",1,Parameters!TodaysDate.Value))) --Wedneday
```

Same for others too... Just by `increment/decrement by 1.`

***To get Days Date in Data***

```
=Format(Parameters!TodaysDate.Value,"dd-MMM-yyyy")
=Format(DateAdd("d", 1, Parameters!TodaysDate.Value),"dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Same for others too... Just by `increment/decrement by 1.`

Here `TodaysDate` would be parameter date or `Now()` Date.

***I have given demo of incremental one, you can change it as per your condition. I think you need to use decrement here. So Instead of 1 you need to use -1.***

This will give you output like below,

[image]